# re.sub() with replacement function that has side effects

Tags: python, regex, replace, side-effects

Today I came across the following construct:

```
import re
l = list('1234')
print(re.sub('.', lambda _: l.pop(0), 'abcd'))
```

Basically, it uses `sub` with a `repl` function that has side effects.

**Arguable stylistic issues aside, is this even well defined?**

For example, I could not find anywhere in the docs that guarantees that `repl` would be called on the matches *in any particular order* (nor indeed *exactly once*, though the official wording is somewhat open to interpretation). Are there any other issues with this code, actual or potential?

Comment: AFAICT, you're correct, and the behavior of this library function is not sufficiently well-defined to make the code in question safe.

Comment: `repl` is called when a pattern is found, and as far as i know regex proceeds matching from left to right, so i don't see any reason for `repl` to be randomly called, seems pretty much same on Docs too [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: @CodeManiac: For one thing, one could easily imagine a regex engine that parallelises the matching.  (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7023656)

Comment: @NPE oh didn't knew about it before, thanks for the link though :)

Comment: AFAIK there is no real world regex engine that would start matching in parallel, let alone in python that utilizes parallel programming only by using a few specific modules. Also if you read that paper you linked to, the presented algorithm accepts a very limited subset of regular expressions which wouldn't allow almost any of the existing regex engines to somehow consider it in their implementation. Hence CodeManiac's comment applies.

Comment: @NPE i read that paper, but this can't be case here, as you're replacement is sequential  ( pop will give values sequentially ), moreover IMO parallel regex will be useful when you want to search something, or you're pretty sure which match should be replaced by what

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) of `re.sub`:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the ***leftmost*** non-overlapping
>   occurrences of `pattern` in `string` by the replacement `repl`.

and:

> If `repl` is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern.

It is hence clear that `re.sub` searches from left to right and replaces each occurrence of the given `pattern` with the returning value of the `repl` function. So yes, the behavior of your code is well defined. It is not efficient, however, because you are popping the first item of a list iteratively, which takes a time complexity of *O(n)* per iteration. You can instead use an iterator to achieve the same side effect in *O(1)* time:

```
import re
i = iter('1234')
print(re.sub('.', lambda _: next(i), 'abcd'))
```

This also outputs:

```
1234
```

Comment: FWIW, the way I read "leftmost" in the quote is to resolve the ambiguity around which non-overlapping matches are chosen, not to mandate any particular order in which `repl` is called (though it is, of course, very likely to be called left-to-right).

Comment: Good point. Now that I reread the paragraph I think you are right that the wording "leftmost" is used only to describe "non-overlapping". Consider this a non-answer then. I'll leave it here just for the second part of your question (Are there any other issues with this code, actual or potential?).